# Hibernate silently fails to insert with null FK, no exception thrown

Tags: hibernate

I'm having some problems with Hibernate, which is not throwing exceptions when I expect it to. In a nutshell, I have an entity mapping to a table with a required FK (table generated by Hibernate); if the FK is specified properly in Java, everything goes fine. If, however, the FK is omitted, the entity is not saved to the DB. Fine -- but I'm not getting an exception at `session.save()` time, nor even at `transaction.commit()`; I only become aware of the problem when I attempt to load the entity. This makes debugging a nightmare. Surely Hibernate *ought* to be issuing some kind of error when I commit, at the latest?

I have no idea where the error might come from, so I'm not very sure how to include appropriately specific information. Any hints welcomed.

Pseudocode:

```
try {
    tx = session.beginTransaction();

    MyEntity me = new MyEntity();
    me.setName("Foo");
    // Omitting to call me.setSomeFK(someOtherEntity);
    session.save(me);

    tx.commit();
    System.out.println("Everything is OK");
}
catch (Exception e) {
    tx.rollback();
}
```

Sadly, it thinks that "`Everything is OK`". Everything is *not* OK.

---

Entity code (sample):

Unfortunately I can't show the whole thing, but

`GenericParticipantEntity.java`:

```
@Entity
@Table
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@DiscriminatorColumn(
    name = "participant_type",
    discriminatorType = DiscriminatorType.STRING,
    length = 16
)
abstract public class GenericParticipantEntity {
    private long participantId;
    private StatEventEntity event;
    private SeasonEventEntity seasonEvent;
    // A bunch of other fields

    @Id
    @Column(name = "participantId")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    public long getParticipantId() {
        return participantId;
    }
    public void setParticipantId(long participantId) {
        this.participantId = participantId;
    }

    @ManyToOne(targetEntity = StatEventEntity.class, optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "stat_event_id")
    public StatEventEntity getEvent() {
        return event;
    }
    public void setEvent(StatEventEntity event) {
        this.event = event;
    }

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "season_event_id", nullable = false)
    public SubSeasonEventEntity getSeasonEvent() {
        return seasonEvent;
    }
    public void setSeasonEvent(SubSeasonEventEntity seasonEvent) {
        this.seasonEvent = seasonEvent;
    }
}
```

`SpecificParticipant.java` (this one really contains no code):

```
@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("specific1")
public class SpecificParticipant extends GenericParticipantEntity { }
```

Usage:

```
Transaction tx;
Long id = null;
try {
    tx = session.beginTransaction();
    SpecificParticipant somePlayer = new SpecificParticipant();
    somePlayer.setEvent(someEvent);
    id = session.save(somePlayer);
    tx.commit();
}
catch (Throwable e) {
    if (tx != null) tx.rollback();
    throw e;
}
```

Note that I'm forgetting to set the `seasonEvent` property, so of course the `INSERT` query will ultimately fail -- as it should; that's an error on my part. What puzzles me is that Hibernate throws no exception here; instead I discover the problem when I attempt to load the object based on the `id`, there's nothing in the DB to load.

The SQL is generated entirely by Hibernate, so if there's an error in the DDL, it's surely due to an error in the Java code.

Comment: Do you have a `not null` constraint in the database? If notn then add one.

Comment: I do have a `not null` constraint -- presumably this is why the data doesn't end up saved properly.

Comment: Show us the code of the entity and the SQL code used to create the table. I don't see how this could be possible, unless you set the flush mode of the session to MANUAL.

Comment: Do you see an insert SQL being issued when turning SQL logging on? What happens if you call session.flush() before committing?

Comment: Interestingly, when I changed from a temporary MySQL dev environment to our production MS SQL Server environment, the problem went away (i.e. it now gives errors when I expect to see errors). Curious, since my MySQL tables are all InnoDB and should support FK checks. So now I can't *reproduce* the issue unless, presumably, I revert environments...